# 0.5px margin between RowDefintions?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, margin

Apologies if I'm going mad, but as shown in the following image, each `RowDefinition` inside my grid appears to be adding '0.5'px vertical margin to itself.

It's a completely blank project, created from scratch.

Have I remembered this incorrectly or is something up?

```
<Grid UseLayoutRounding="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Row="0" Width="40" Height="10" Background="Aqua" Margin="1"/>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Width="40" Height="10" Background="Red" Margin="1"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]
Note, it's not just Visual Studio's Designer window that's showing this, binaries are exhibiting the same.

Comment: You have `Margin="1"` on each `Border` element..........

Comment: @Zack Yes, but `1.5` is being rendered

Comment: Remove `UseLayoutRounding="True"` and you're good.

Comment: @ChrisW. That didn't do anything for me...

Comment: @maxp I see what you mean now. I have no idea what is going on. I added 4 more `RowDefinition` elements, and 4 more `Border` elements, and set each border in a new row, and it is like every odd numbered `Border` has some built in margin on the bottom. I'm not sure where it's coming from.

Comment: Oh right, sorry also remove `SnapsToDevicePixels`

Comment: @ChrisW. Please try your suggestions before posting them...

Comment: @Clemens I did, it wasn't a suggestion...was just rushed by the phone at the time, besides already knowing how it works but that's why it was just left in comments. Cheers.

Comment: @ChrisW. What's your point? It still shows 1.5, at least on my side.

Comment: @Clemens - did you try? It shows 1 on mine, want a screen shot also?

Comment: @ChrisW. That's what I just posted: "It still shows 1.5, at least on my side"

Comment: @Clemens see answer.

Answer (score 0):

So if you remove both of the properties as mentioned in the comments that are giving permission to adjust based on the measure/arrange pass in this scenario you should be back down to your desired margin.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Row="0" Width="40" Height="10" Background="Aqua" Margin="1"/>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Width="40" Height="10" Background="Red" Margin="1"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Clemens hmmm, I just loaded it into a fresh proj so I'm not sure what would be different? If it turns out incorrect of course I'll del it.